# Enumerable Sets

Tags: general-topology

If $E$ is an enumerable set of $R^n$, is $R^n-E$ an open subset of $R^n$?
May I conclude that $E$ is a discrete metric space for the euclidian metric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because $E$ may not be closed: for example take a sequenve converging to a point and remove the limit point. This is not closed (by sequential criterion) and thus its complementary is not open.

To give an explicit example, let $n=1$ and consider
$$E=\{ \frac{1}{n} \mid n\in \mathbb{N} \}$$
This is not closed, because if you take the obvious sequence in $E$ converging to $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$, the limit of this sequence (that is, $0$) is not in $E$.

On the other hand, if we consider now $E$ the same as before but including the $0$, then it is closed, but it is not discrete (because $0$ is an accumulation point).

You can also mix these two examples to produce non closed and non discrete countable subsets of any euclidean space.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain that mathematically? I'm new to this theme and I started the course two weeks ago, so I'm struggling to understand all this. I tried to do the exercise for when E is finite and infinite. And I proved that it is open if it is finite, now I need to answer for the infinite case.

Comment: Okay I'll add some details

Comment: Thanks man. I think this is the most difficult course I have taken. Even abstract Algebra, Logic, etc. feels easier for me.

Comment: But if E is a finite set, can I state that the statements I made are true?

Comment: Do you know books to study topology? I have "Elementos de Topologia Geral" by Elon Lages Lima and "Introduction to metric and Topological Spaces" by William Angus Sutherland. What is the best way to study this?

Comment: Yes, points are closed so finite union of points is also closed, and for discrete find a minimum distance between points, then consider raidus half of this distance and take balls around the points. You see then that the induce topology is the discrete one. You use finitedness to make sure this minimum is not an infimum and is not zero. Good luck with the subject! P.s. if you are new on Math.se, remember that you can accept correct answers :)

Comment: As reference I used Willard ("General Topology" I think) and these books on counterexamples in topology (shouldn't be difficult to find their titles). Another thing if you are new at Math.se: try not to use too many comments, this isn't supposed to be a chat! If you do, the webpage will soon suggest you to use the chat instead. Just so you know!

Comment: Ok, I won't bother you more. Thanks for the help!